# VLC-LUA: using net.stat

Tags: lua, vlc, stat

I am trying to write a function that finds the first .waste dir in one of the parent dirs (e.g. .. ../.. ../../..).

For this I need to see if the dir exists. For that I would imagine `net.stat` would be useful.

But this fails:

```
vlc.net.stat("/")
```

with:

```
lua warning: Error while running script /home/tange/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/WasteBasket.lua, function activate(): /home/tange/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/WasteBasket.lua:42: attempt to index field 'net' (a nil value)
```

From the error it almost looks as if `vlc.net` does not contain `vlc.net.stat` - but `net.stat` is listed on: 
https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt

An example using `net.stat` for VLC-LUA will be very appreciated.

Comment: The error messages indicate that `vlc.net` doesn't exist, not `vlc.net.stat`. And the examples in the readme use `net` by itself, not `vlc.net`.

Comment: From https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt (section 3): "All VLC specifics modules are in the "vlc" object.". And I get same error if I remove vlc. Do you not get any error?

Comment: I didn't try it; just making an observation from the readme.

Comment: you might want to post your script. 1 line of code isn't that informative...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `os.execute("cd " .. dir)` to see if a dir exists.

It works, but I regard it as a hack.

```
function directory_exists(dir)
  -- Simple checker if dir exists
  -- shell quote the dirname
  dir, _ = dir:gsub("([\002-\009\011-\026\\#?`(){}%[%]^*<>=~|; \"!$&'\130-\255])", "\\%1")
  dir, _ = dir:gsub("\n", "'\n'")
  return os.execute("cd " .. dir)
end
```